# PHP Cross comparing two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in the following structure

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => John Wayne
        [email] => john.wayne@email.com
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Bruce Lee
        [email] => bruceless@email.com
    )
)
```

I then have a second array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Group One
        [members] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lora Day
            [1] => James McKay
            [2] => John Wayne
        )
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Group Two
        [members] => Array
        (
            [0] => John Wayne
            [1] => Bruce Lee
            [2] => Brendon Shell
        )
    )
)
```

The first array will have all the users with  their email addresses.  The second array has all the groups, and the names of the users within them groups.  What I need to do is somehow get the users email address linked to their user in a group.  So I was thinking about somehow creating a third array like so

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Group One
        [members] => Array
        (
            [Lora Day] => lora@email.com
            [James McKay] => james@email.com
            [John Wayne] => john.wayne@email.com
        )
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Group Two
        [members] => Array
        (
            [John Wayne] => john.wayne@email.com
            [Bruce Lee] => bruceless@email.com
            [Brendon Shell] => brendon@email.com
        )
    )
)
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?  I can see in the docs [array_diff_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) But not too sure how I could make use of this in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can not do that only with `array_diff_assoc`, you must use 2 loop or loop and `array_diff_assoc`

Comment: And post your attempts too

Comment: So, what have you tried yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best way to do it but this would be a way of doing it without array_diff_assoc

```
foreach($secondarray as $key => $secondarrayinner){
    foreach($secondarrayinner['members'] as $innerkey => $row){
        foreach($firstarray as $row2){
            if($row2['name'] == $row){
                $secondarray[$key]['members'][$row2['name']] = $row2['email'];
                unset($secondarray[$key]['members'][$innerkey]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Loops through both arrays and if the names are the same it will set a new element. The name will be set as the key and the value is set to the email. After that it unsets the old value. That way any users where no email was found will still be in there

Comment: Perfect thanks, will use this as an example to create my own

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through second array and match with the name and create new one using two foreach

```
$arrayOne = array('0' => array('name' => 'John Wayne','email' => 'john.wayne@email.com'),

                  '1' => array('name' => 'Bruce Lee','email' => 'bruceless@email.com')
                 );

$arrayTwo = array('0' => array('name' => 'Group One','members' => array('0'=>'Lora Day','1'=>'James McKay','2'=>'John Wayne')),

                  '1' => array('name' => 'Group Two','members' => array('0'=>'John Wayne','1'=>'Bruce Lee','2'=>'Brendon Shell'))
                 );

 foreach($arrayTwo as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value['members'] as $ke=>$val){
         if($arrayOne[$key]['name']==$val){
            $arrayTwo[$key]['members'][$val] = $arrayOne[$key]['email'];
           }
           unset($arrayTwo[$key]['members'][$ke]);
       }
   }

echo '<pre>';print_r($arrayTwo);
```